# Make table header fixed when scrolling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using `Bootstrap V4 alpha 6` along with `Angular 5` to create a table with a fixed header when scrolling. However, I can't seem to get it to work.

Note: The `navbar` is `fixed-top`

Things I've tried:

1) Add `fixed-top` class to `thead`.

2)

```
thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

3)

```
thead {
  display:block;
}
```

4) Lots of CSS but nothing works because the table is responsive and scrollable and there are multiple header rows.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false"
    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
<img src="./assets/logo.png" width="200" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
</a>
</nav>
<table class="table table-responsive w-100 d-block d-md-table table-bordered table-striped table-fixed">
<thead class="sticky-top">
<tr>
  <th colspan="16" class="text-center">PROJECT 1</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th rowspan="2">WON</th>
  <th rowspan="2">LST #</th>
  <th rowspan="2">FLR #</th>
  <th colspan="3">GLS</th>
  <th colspan="7">FRMS</th>
  <th rowspan="2">Scheduled Date</th>
  <th rowspan="2">Cmplt Date</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>G Reqd</th>
  <th colspan="2">G Rcvd (%)</th>
  <th>Frms Reqd</th>
  <th colspan="2">Frms Ass (%)</th>
  <th colspan="2">Frms Line (%)</th>
  <th colspan="2">Frms Cmplt (%)</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let project of projectData">
  <td>{{project.ordernumber}}</td>
  <td>{{project.ListNumber}}</td>
  <td>{{project.floorID}}</td>
    <td>{{project.glassRequired}}</td>
    <td>{{project.glassReceived}}</td>
    <td>{{project.glassReceivedPercent}}</td>
  <td>{{project.framesRequired}}</td>
  <td>{{project.framesAssembled}}</td>
  <td>{{project.framesAssembledPercent}}%</td>
  <td>{{project.framesGlazed}}</td>
  <td>{{project.framesGlazedPercent}}%</td>
  <td>{{project.framesShipped}}</td>
  <td>{{project.framesShippedPercent}}%</td>
  <td>{{project.deliverydate}}</td>
 <td>Not Shipped Yet</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I've also created a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/FpyPcnWwxHa21VfZ07iJ).

Comment: You can take a look at this https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/oVlgM

Comment: I have tried this in the past, and it's just not possible to remove a table header from the table visually like this.  It screws with the table layout and just doesn't work in general.  What i did before was make a totally separate table that only contained the header, no body.  Size all the columns to match via JS, and then hide/show it based on the page scroll position.  it's a lot of work, but it does look nice!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to create your own JavaScript function to manipulate the behavior as required. Play around with the following snippet code to meet your expectations.

```js
document.onscroll = function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 50) {
    $("thead").css({
      "position": "fixed",
      "top": "0px"
    });
    $("th").css({"padding":"15px 66px", "margin":"auto"});
  } else {
    $("thead").css({
      "position": "relative",
      "top": "0px"
    });
  }
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-borderless table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Full Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sam Tomashi</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>D.R.Congo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Molly Akinyi</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>Kenya</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sam Tomashi</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>D.R.Congo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Molly Akinyi</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>Kenya</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sam Tomashi</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>D.R.Congo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Molly Akinyi</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>Kenya</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sam Tomashi</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>D.R.Congo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Molly Akinyi</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>Kenya</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sam Tomashi</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>D.R.Congo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Molly Akinyi</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>Kenya</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sam Tomashi</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>D.R.Congo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Molly Akinyi</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>Kenya</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sam Tomashi</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>D.R.Congo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Molly Akinyi</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>Kenya</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sam Tomashi</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>D.R.Congo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Molly Akinyi</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>Kenya</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Play around with the jQuery css to make the header width appear as desired on scroll. in the snippet above the width is not full.

Comment: It depends on the css. I believe that can easily be sorted by adjusting the width of the header on scroll.