# Make table header fixed while scrolling but the columns width to still dynamically change based on the content in the body rows

Tags: bootstrap-4

So my problem is I need to have a table with fixed header while scrolling down the window, but if I use position:fixed, then I need to set up a manual width for the column headers, and the point is that they need to expand based on the content.
Because if not, when the content on the body has more text, then they tend to overlap to the next column header.

Here's my code : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/362/)

```
<table class="table table-striped col-md-12 table-condensed cf">
      <thead class="table-bordered cf">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Last name</th>
          <th>Color</th>
          <th>Data</th>
          <th>More data</th>
          <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
             <tr>
          <td > My Name</td>
          <td>Brown</td>
          <td>red</td>
          <td>sadfasf</td>
          <td>sfs</td>              
          <td>dsfsf</td>

        </tr>
             <tr>
          <td > My Name</td>
          <td>Brown</td>
          <td>red</td>
          <td>sadfasf</td>
          <td>sfs</td>              
          <td>dsfsf</td>

        </tr>
             <tr>
          <td > My Name</td>
          <td>Brown</td>
          <td>red</td>
          <td>sadfasf</td>
          <td>sfs</td>              
          <td>dsfsf</td>

        </tr>
             <tr>
          <td > My Name</td>
          <td>Brown</td>
          <td>red</td>
          <td>sadfasf</td>
          <td>sfs</td>              
          <td>dsfsf</td>

        </tr>
             <tr>
          <td > My Name</td>
          <td>Brown</td>
          <td>red</td>
          <td>sadfasf</td>
          <td>sfs</td>              
          <td>dsfsf</td>

        </tr>
             <tr>
          <td > My Name</td>
          <td>Brown</td>
          <td>red</td>
          <td>sadfasf</td>
          <td>sfs</td>              
          <td>dsfsf</td>

        </tr>
             <tr>
          <td > My Name</td>
          <td>Brown</td>
          <td>red</td>
          <td>sadfasf</td>
          <td>sfs</td>              
          <td>dsfsf</td>

        </tr>
             <tr>
          <td > My Name</td>
          <td>Brown</td>
          <td>red</td>
          <td>sadfasf</td>
          <td>sfs</td>              
          <td>dsfsf</td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```
  thead{
  position:fixed; }
```

Comment: Your question is duble for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638015/bootstrap-4-how-to-make-table-header-fixed-when-scrolling