# Reduce Bootstrap 4 Card Z-index less than table thead

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a Table with a fixed header as below. The problem is that the card elements scroll on top of the fixed header. I have tried increasing `z-index` of `thead` and decreasing `z-index` of the card element. Nothing seems to be working.

```js
document.getElementById("scrollarea").addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var translate = "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
  $(this).find("thead")[0].style.transform = translate;
});
```

```css
#scrollarea {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="scrollarea">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Row 1</th>
        <th>Row 2</th>
        <th>Row 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want to make the `thead` be on top when the `div` is scrolled.

Any kind of help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638015/bootstrap-4-how-to-make-table-header-fixed-when-scrolling

Comment: This doesn't help @לבנימלכה because I am doing the same thing but the card elements are not being scrolled below thead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing table to div and add .sticky-top to the parent div.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the position property on scroll and also use z-index:

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the navbar
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
/* Style the navbar */
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* The sticky class is added to the navbar with JS when it reaches its scroll position */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFF;
}

/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the navigation bar gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */
.sticky + .tbody {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="scrollarea">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead id="navbar">
      <tr>
        <th>Row 1</th>
        <th>Row 2</th>
        <th>Row 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me because the table is not the first element in my code. The code I gave was just a part of the code which I had problems with. Making `thead` as `position: fixed; top: 0` will put the thead element on top of my navbar.

Comment: it now uses the offset of the to be fixed element @VishnuYS

Comment: Its still not working properly as expected. The thead shrinks as soon as its scrolled.